# increase date based on ${copyrightYear}

Tags: javascript, freemarker, copyright-display

I need your help in creating a script on Freemarker with a list of year options based on ${copyrightYear} as a base year. I will use this on credit card expiration options that will have an output like this.

```
 <option value="" name="">Year</option>
 <option value="2011">2011</option>
 <option value="2012">2012</option>
 <option value="2013">2013</option>
 <option value="2014">2014</option>
 <option value="2015">2015</option>
 ...until 2021
```

2011 should be ${copyrightYear} and it will increment 10 times until it reaches the year 2021. I want this to be automated every year. Any help from you guys will be much appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming your model is [setup to use static methods](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html#autoid_54).  This should work,

```
<#setting number_format="##">
<#assign currentYear = statics["java.util.Calendar"].getInstance().getTime()?string("yyyy")?number>
<option value="" name="">Year</option>
<#list currentYear..(currentYear + 10) as year>
    <option value="${year}">${year}</option>
</#list>
```

There are several ways to get the current year.  If you need to, make sure you get the current year in the correct locale.

**Edit 1:**

As Chaquotay graciously noted, with FreeMarker 2.3.17 .now can be used to get current time instead of the static call to Calendar.

Comment: With FreeMarker 2.3.17 and newer you don't need ``statics["java.util.Calendar"].getInstance().getTime()`` any more, you can simply use the special variable ``.now``.